# How can I get "DOCUMENT_ROOT" in phpbb 3.1?

Tags: phpbb3

I have tried to use this

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/MyClass.php';
```

But I got this message

> Illegal use of $_SERVER. You must use the request class or request_var() to access input data

I have attempted to use request_var(), but it doesn't work.

How can  I get  "DOCUMENT_ROOT" in phpbb 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the next decision of this problem - use filter_input instead of $_SERVER.

```
  require filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/lib/MyClass.php';
```